# Unable to compare the variable declared as a success/failure state via bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, command

I have created a bat file to find the folders that have the subfolders in the list of folders defined in the master file.

**Script:**

```
@echo off
REM SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in (D:\Temp\A\folder_creation\FRONT_OFFICE_SERVER.txt) do (
pause
echo %%a
(echo %%a |find /I "\" > null && set COUNTER='SUB' || set COUNTER='NO_SUB') >> abc.log
pause
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo counter is !COUNTER!
pause
set SUB='SUB'
IF !COUNTER!=='%SUB%' ( 
echo %%a has a subfolder
pause
SET !COUNTER!=ABC
) ELSE (
echo %%a doesnt have a subfolder
pause
SET !COUNTER!=ABC
)
)
```

**File content of FRONT_OFFICE_SERVER.txt**

```
ABC
DEF
ABC\DEF
ABC\GHI
TEMP
A
B\A
```

Here the Script runs and loops the folder names mentioned in the text file and enters the loop as per the validation provided.But each time the loop goes it either enters IF clause or the else clause but not as per the subfolder presence.

My intention is to run the set of commands under If clause if a subfolder doesnt exist and else part commands if the sbfolder exists.

I feel this is because of the if validation where i am missing a single quote or double quotes for the local variable used.

Could some one help me in this please as this small pending stuff has made the entire work since yesterday?

Comment: Any early response is much appreciated as the rest of the work is dependent on the above to be resolved. :(

Comment: Add `echo IF !COUNTER!=='%SUB%'` right after `set SUB='SUB'`  you can see something wrong and probably unexpected like `IF 'SUB' ==''SUB''`

Comment: @JosefZ I have tried removing the quots in `set SUB=SUB` and that didnt work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example script showing a simpler thought process:

```
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%I In (D:\Temp\A\folder_creation\FRONT_OFFICE_SERVER.txt) Do (
    If "%%~nI" Equ "%%~I" (
        Echo=[%%I] No Sub - run the set of commands
    ) Else (
        Echo=[%%~I] Sub exists - run the part commands
    )
)
Pause
```

Hope it helps you out,

Comment: Can you please help with the difference between using the `"%%~nI"` and `"%%~I"`

Comment: **%~I**  - expands **%I** removing any surrounding quotes ("), **%~nI** - expands **%I** to a file/folder name only. In this case everything after the last backslash is seen as a file/folder name,. The logic is if the word is different when expanded then it must be a subfolder.

Comment: @user2075017, read the help for the `FOR ` command. It explains it quite well.